# What's the public availability of data gathered by NASA probes?

Tags: probe, nasa, raw-data, scientific-data

The probes sent by [NASA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA) generate a lot of data for scientists to study, but how available is it to non-NASA affiliated scientists?

For instance, would I (a layperson) be able to get the raw data collected by the Mars rovers?

Comment: This question is also of interest to the folks at [OpenData.SE].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the NASA webpage [Open Government Initiative](http://www.nasa.gov/open/data.html), there are several repositories of raw data from NASA missions.  These are sorted by categories, however, as this site is a bit dated, the links are sometimes broken - but is included to give you an idea what is actually there.

The official US government website [Data.gov](http://catalog.data.gov/organization/about/nasa-gov) also has over 3000 data sets from NASA alone.

**As a specific example**, about the Mars rovers, an example of the data available is from NASA's [PDS: The Planetary Atmospheres Data Node](http://atmos.pds.nasa.gov/data_and_services/atmospheres_data/Mars/Mars.html) (Scroll down the page and you'll see the Mars rover data for this context.

Comment: For rover stuff you definitely want the [geosciences node](http://geo.pds.nasa.gov/), not just the atmospheres node.  E.g. [MER](http://geo.pds.nasa.gov/missions/mer/) and [MSL](http://geo.pds.nasa.gov/missions/msl/).

Answer (score 4):

All NASA data is to be released to the public within 1 year of it's collection, and is released to the [Planetary Data System](http://pds.nasa.gov/). The 1 year is to give the scientists a chance to publish on the research they have worked long and hard to colelct.

Comment: It varies from project to project.  For the NASA Mars Exploration Program missions, it's [six months](http://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/missions/mep/mepdmp.pdf).  In addition, all MER and MSL images are released to the public nearly in real time in an uncalibrated, compressed form.

Comment: @MarkAdler: Some programs are better than others, but the requirement is to release the data at least once a year.

Comment: Now you're quoting a frequency, not a latency.  Again projects are different.  Most that have a _latency_ of one year have a _frequency_ of releases every six months.

Comment: That's for probes to other planets. Data for other types of science (Earth, solar, astronomical) get archived elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The [Mikulski Archive for Space Telescopes (MAST)](http://archive.stsci.edu/) contains a considerable amount of raw and normalized astronomy data including that from the Hubble Space Telescope, GALEX, FUSE, and Kepler.